# Magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 [...] \DataSetup::__construct() [...] must be an instance [...]

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, fatal-error

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04 with PHP 7.0.33 and a working Magento 2.1.7 installation with a working (up to yesterday) module for credit card payment

after adding some new modules, compiling and deploying without any problem the system still works fine

but when I try to checkout and confirm on credit card payment the checkout page reloads, it's not redirecting anymore to the credit card portal for entering my information:

This is my credit card selection
[image: Credit card payment method]

When I click on the *Completa ordine* button (Complete Order)

The loading spinner appears and then disappears again on the same page.

in my browser console I see this error:

> VM16995:1 POST http://domain.com/rest/store/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is the network trace

[image: Network trace]

and in my error.log I see this message:

> [Sat May 25 10:20:14.839259 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4427] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:13271] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /var/www/domain/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/DataSetup.php:57\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))\n#1 /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Setup\\M...', Array)\n#2 /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\S...\n', referer: http://domain.com/checkout/

In the stack trace on error.log I can't find any reference to one of my modules, even if the presence of `create('Magento\\\\S...` at the end of the trace make me think that the trace has been cut for some reason

I've searched for such errors on DataSetup::__construct() but it seems that this error could happen during modules installation, I couldn't find anything about this error on an API call

the rest of the system seems to work fine and I don't have other messages on error.log

how can I solve this?

**EDIT**
I Just noticed that the error happens on any payment method, not only on credit card, every time I click on complete order on any payment method

Answer (score 0):

**Run This Command and Try :-**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code var/di

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After Execute Give Permission This Folder **`var/` `generated/` `pub/`**

[Reference Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3963)

[Reference Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4896)

Comment: Done, nothing changed: No errors during setup and deploy, everything works, payment confirmation fails